# Best approach DB hit with small amount of data / single hit with huge data

Tags: database, dto, transfer

I am working in a windows form application with 3 layered. I have confusion regarding data transfer.

I have a page with data grid contains some items. The grid is in multi-tab so first tab is items and second tab is features. When user select second tab, the grid refreshes the features of selected item.

Here I have ItemDTO consists of List of Items and List of Features. How I get data from the database

1. Select all items and Features so that I populate features using itemID joining in LINQ. Here only single DB hit but my confusion is how big the data is. Because for each item multiple features are available.
2. In the tab selected index changed I need to get the features based on selected item in the same DTO. Here data is ok but each tab change I need to get the data. Also I designed DTO for the page / function so anyway item also need to be populated when features populated. This is unnecessary. Or my DTO design is wrong?

Which one is better approach? Or any other alternative?

Comment: It depends on if your data needs to be real-time or based for viewing pleasure. If you store the features after the first grid hit then you can show all the data you need all day long. If you need to update the data then you probably want to "refresh" your features on tab change.

Comment: thanks. But how the general approach will be. Actually we are using jquery and wcf service . So how will be the best approach

Comment: Then you should use the tab change and load new data.

Comment: Thanks so in tab chnage we are getting new data instaed of download all data and filter. am i right ?